# Select multiple entities in a datasource with Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I am trying to write a function where I can select multiple buildings of GeoJSON and/or CZML in Cesium
for example with the ctrl button held down, I will be able to create a list to select several buildings, and also change the color of the selected building as well.

I can change the color of one selected building now, and was told I should use the (entity.push) to add to the a list. but I'm still stuck!

Here is my [initial code](https://jsfiddle.net/bhoj6d0L/)

```
*var scene = viewer.scene;
var handler = viewer.screenSpaceEventHandler;
handler.setInputAction(function(click) {
var pickedObject = scene.pick(click.position);
if (Cesium.defined(pickedObject) ) {
    highlightedEntity=  pickedObject.id;
    // console.log (pickedObject.id);

} else{
    highlightedEntity = undefined;
}

},Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK);*
```

can someone help me out in completing it?

Here you can find a sample of the [geojson](https://github.com/Ayah93/Testing/blob/master/test_select.geojson)

Comment: I see a variable named `highlightedEntity` here, but I don't see how the entity actually gets visually highlighted.  Do you have custom code for this?  (Sadly, you will need custom code for this, as Cesium's built-in SelectionIndicator only handles single entity selection.  Multi-select tends to be too app-specific to be put in core Cesium, I believe).

Comment: I was told this is possible by pushing the selected entities into a list, something like: 

var scene = viewer.scene;
var handler = viewer.screenSpaceEventHandler;
handler.setInputAction(function(click) {
    var pickedObject = scene.pick(click.position);
    if (Cesium.defined(pickedObject) ) {
        highlightedEntities.push(pickedObject.id);
        console.log (pickedObject.id);        
    }
    
}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK, Cesium.KeyboardEventModifier.CTRL);


But I'm having a hard time figuring it out... any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, you can push entities into a list named highlightedEntities.  But you need to have your own code to highlight all the entities in your highlightedEntities list.  Cesium doesn't offer such a list out-of-the-box.

Comment: so... can  you help me out with it? do you have any idea on how to start it?

Comment: No, sorry, and Stack Overflow isn't the right venue for soliciting code-writing services anyway.  Look at Cesium demos, read the forum, etc., but you'll have better luck with questions that don't request large chunks of code to be written for you.  Sorry!